# Localize notification payload

Tags: windows-phone-7, localization, push-notification, mpns

I am currently developing a localized application which uses push notifications. I would like to know if it is possible to localize the strings that are sent in the notification message, in the `Text` element for toast notification and in the `Title` element for a tile notification. I would like to use the localized resource strings I have created to localize the rest of the application.

I have seen that it is possible to localize the application title by using the `'@'` character in the main tile by following this guidance:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967550(v=VS.92).aspx
but unfortunately I do not know if this behaviour can be reproduced whilst receiving a push notification. So finally, is there a way to localize push notifications?

Comment: Perhaps you could pass your culture information when you subscribe to the push notifications and have your server delivered them localized.

Comment: Yeah, I also thought of that, it seems there's no other workaround... Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also posted this issue on the msdn site:

http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/96082.aspx

Therefore I will implement l8n on the server side as it seems to be the only way to localize notifications' payload.

Thank you Heinrich.