# Localization of Toast Notification in windows phone

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0, windows-8, windows-mobile

was just trying to localize  the toast received from the MNPS in windows phone app. is there a way to do it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349117/localize-notification-payload & http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/7cd50899-8fd3-42d3-af85-97af4af85bd9/localize-notifications-payload?forum=wpnotifications

Comment: are you tryinf to do it using notification hub of azure mobile services

Comment: no tanuj we are not using azure mobile services